# Docker healthcheck file incorrectly not found

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, health-check

I have a container running a custom Apache image. The image has these entries:

```
COPY healthcheck.sh /root/healthcheck.sh
RUN chmod +x /root/healthcheck.sh
HEALTHCHECK --interval=600s --timeout=5s CMD /root/healthcheck.sh
```

This setup used to work fine. But after I updated my docker to `20.10.7` the healthcheck is giving problems. The container is now 'unhealthy'.

I checked the logs for the error, it turns out, the healthcheck.sh script can not be found:

```
      "ExitCode": 127,
      "Output": "/bin/sh: /root/healthcheck.sh: not found\n"
```

I tried running the `/root/healthcheck.sh` script manually (the file does exist), both from inside and outside the container, and it runs fine, it gives back a 0 exit code.

Stat of the file:

```
  File: /root/healthcheck.sh
  Size: 147         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 34h/52d Inode: 4661497     Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
```

I set the permissions to 777 as a test, but it doesn't matter.
Any ideas?

Comment: What is the very first line of the file (it should be something like `#!/bin/sh`)?  Could the file accidentally have gotten added with DOS line endings?

Comment: @DavidMaze the file starts with `#!/bin/sh`. And I set the line endings to unix using vi, just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Please add sh to your HEALTHCHECK

```
HEALTHCHECK --interval=600s --timeout=5s CMD sh /root/healthcheck.sh
```